# Delete an element via an external element

Tags: jquery

I need to delete an element via an external element. In the following example the user would focus on a .content element, then the .delete-element will show. By a click on that .delete-element the focused .content-element should be deleted.

My problem is how to identify the element. I tried to give the element an id/class, but as I click on the delete-element the blur function (which is needed for the case the user don't delete but click somewhere else) gets the class removed first.

Maybe my attempt (by adding a temporary class) is the wrong way...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="delete" style="display: none;">Delete</div>

<div class="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.delete').on('click', function () {
    $('.active').remove();
});
$('.content').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.delete').show();
});
$('.content').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.delete').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ze1kvh0g/

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ze1kvh0g/9/

I think I need the blur-function: Maybe the user is doing something completly different after focusing a .content-element (i.e. scrolling or clicking on anything else of the website). In that case the focus gets lost and the active-class have to be removed.

Am I wrong with that?

**Update 2:**

This is a working solution (combination of Pr0gr4mm3r's and Moshtaf's answer) : http://jsfiddle.net/ze1kvh0g/13/
Don't know if the code could be optimized to get a little smaller...

```
var activeElement, isOnDeleteButton = false;
$(".delete").hover(function () {
    isOnDeleteButton = true;
}, function () {
    isOnDeleteButton = false;
});

$('.delete').on('click', function () {
    if (activeElement) {
        activeElement.remove();
        delete activeElement;
    }
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.content').on('focus', function () {
    activeElement = $(this);
    $('.delete').show();
});
$('.content').on('blur', function () {
    if (!isOnDeleteButton) $('.delete').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
var isOnDeleteButton = false;
$( ".delete" ).mouseenter(function() {isOnDeleteButton = true;});
$( ".delete" ).mouseleave(function() {isOnDeleteButton = false;});

$('.delete').on('click', function () {
    $('.active').remove();
    $('.delete').hide();
});
$('.content').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.delete').show();
});
$('.content').on('blur', function () {
    if (!isOnDeleteButton){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.delete').hide();
    }
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ze1kvh0g/3/)**

Comment: "Try this" answers are not generally useful. Say *what* you did/changed, and *why*.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. I just thinking of making the code a little bit smaller... (maybe using hover and toggle)

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest way is to just temporary save your element.
In this way you can also avoid poluting your elements with temporary css-classes, if not needed for styling.

```
var activeElement;
$('.delete').on('click', function () {
    if(activeElement) {
        activeElement.remove();
        delete activeElement;
    }
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.content').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.delete').show();
    activeElement = $(this);
});
$('.content').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.delete').hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ze1kvh0g/10/

Comment: Except that there's missing delete.hide() in the click function I can't see any other issue. While I tried it, there was no "active" class. Maybe you are referring to the contenteditable="true"?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your `blur` function:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function () {
    $('.active').remove();    
    // $('.delete').hide(); -> only if you want to hide the Delete button every time
});
$('.content').on('focus', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.delete').show();
});
```

I removed the `blur` function because when the user clicks on another element, all active elements will be disabled.

Comment: By removing the 'blur' handler, you also removed part of the functionality. The 'delete' button got hidden when losing focus on the content items. Now the delete button is always shown after selecting the a content item, but is not hidden when clicking elsewhere, except the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

try this way , no need to define "blur" just remove previous active and add active to current content. and that way it becomes simple

```
  $('.delete').on('click', function () {

       $('.active').remove();
       $('.delete').hide();
  });

  $('.content').on('focus', function () {

    $('.content').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.delete').show();

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ze1kvh0g/8/